# Write data from cotroller to view javascript

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I need to get some data from a controller into the JavaScript in a view.
I have the following method:

```
     private JsonResult GetSection()
         {
            string orderId = (orderService.GetOrder(UserSEssion)).Id.ToString();
            return this.Json(orderId);
          }
```

I have the following in the view:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         lpAddVars('page', 'Section', + GetId()+); 
         function GetId() {
         $.getJSON("/Checkout/GetSection", null, function (data) {
         someThing = data;
        });
      }
     </script>
```

I would appreciate any help in how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the orderId already part of your model?  You would be able to just access it in the view via the model.  If you need the approach you are using I would start by making the method public and you may need to put the http verb attribute on it as well HttpGet

Comment: I tried pulling it from the model, but the  assume the javascript is writen before the model is available as the values were blank